# How to address two different touch screens when they have the same name

Tags: linux, udev, xinput

I have recently bought a new computer with two touchscreens (yoga book 9) and installed linux (Ubuntu 22.04) on it, but it has some issues with automatically managing touch/stylus.

I've worked out how to pull out the EVENT number IDs (/event0, /event1, ... ) of the stylus inputs but I can't distinguish between each of the two screens since they have the same name and physical path when using udeveadm and xinput. I suspect this is due to them both being passed through the same USB hub. The only other things than the INPUT number that seem to change is the USEC_INITIALIZED and MAJOR/MINOR device node, none of which can be used to uniquely identify them.

How can I get a serial number or similar unique identifier for these two so I can automatically configure the screens at startup?

ADDENDUM: at the moment, a script that has to be run by the user is an acceptable solution.

EDIT1: some further details.

`xrandr` gives different names for monitors (eDP-1 and eDP-2), though I can't find any links between these IDs and other ones I've found.

`/dev/input/` has event0 to event21, mouse0 to mouse4, mice and the files by-id and by-parts. In by-id I have:

- usb-INGENIC_Gadget_Serial_and_keyboard_ingenic-event-if03
- usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if02-mouse
- usb-INGENIC_Gadget_Serial_and_keyboard_ingenic-if02-event-kbd
- usb-SEM_USB_Keyboard-event-if01
- usb-INGENIC_Gadget_Serial_and_keyboard_ingenic-if03-event-mouse
- usb-SEM_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd
- usb-INGENIC_Gadget_Serial_and_keyboard_ingenic-if03-mouse
- usb-SunplusIT_Inc_Integrated_Camera_01.00.00-event-if00
- usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if02-event-mouse
- usb-SunplusIT_Inc_Integrated_Camera_01.00.00-event-if02

But the relevant events are both linked to `input/by-id/usb-INGENIC_Gadget_Serial_and_keyboard_ingenic-if03-event-mouse`